# Saving order value to each booking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app as my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Tickets model has the price field and bookings model has the order_quantity field. Right now, I use a model method total_amount in bookings.rb to display the total price ie. (price * order_quantity) in the bookings show page (@booking.total_amount).

Now, in the bookings index page, I use a block to list all the details Buyer name, ticket type, order quantity etc. Here, I'd like to show the total amount as well. What's the best way to do it? Do I need to create a total_price column in the bookings table and save the amount in the create action?

Bookings Index page looks like this:

```
<% @event.bookings.each do |booking| %>
              <td><%= booking.buyer_name %></td>
              <td><%= booking.email %></td>
              <td><%= booking.ticket_id %></td>
              <td><%= booking.order_quantity %></td>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord will return a collection of model instances when you access the relationship in this way. In other words, when you cycle through the bookings, each one is an instance of your model.

For this reason, you can just re-use your method:

```
<td><%= booking.total_amount %></td>
```

Comment: In most usual cases it's best not to add calculated fields to a database on top of the original fields themselves, as this denormalises the data and allows data inconsistencies to occur. (One exception is when actually calculating it on the fly would be too costly, in which case you can cache the values in a field and use systems to ensure data integrity, like background processing.)